# Overheating of the DC/DC LM2596 module when charging batteries

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have built a battery charging unit for my robot as shown in the figure below.
After plugging in the adapter, the converter module gets really hot after a few minutes, I don't really understand why the converter module overheats. Is there something wrong with my work?
Is there an alternative module that I can use instead of the [LM-2596](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf?ts=1665789343927) and solve my problem?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: The LM2596 is a discrete component.  What is the circuit it is connected to?  How much current is your battery charger drawing?

Comment: I don't know how much current it exactly draws, I only know the charger draws a maximum of 3A.The hx-2s charger module : https://usa.banggood.com/HX-2S-A10-2S-8_4V-9V-8A-Li-ion-18650-Lithium-Battery-Charger-Protection-Board-8_4V-Overcurrent-Overcharge-Overdischarge-Protection-p-1528877.html

Comment: Battery charger exact model name is HX-2S-02

Comment: You're running it at 100% rated power, I would expect it to get hot.  What specific part of the converter module is getting hot?

Comment: The wires, LM 2596 Regulator, and Its inductor are getting hot too. But other modules work fine.

Comment: I've mostly had good luck with Banggood, but it could be a counterfeit, fake, or defective unit.

Comment: The HX-2S-02 is a battery protection module. Do you have a link for the LM2596 converter?

Comment: Your charging unit needs a proper LiIon battery charger. The HX-2S-02 is just a BMS. You batteries will not survive this mistreatment for very long.

Comment: Please stop what you are doing and get yourself a li-ion charger instead before you have a fire or fiery explosion.

Comment: I found something as this (for 2 batteries) , but others could do https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mp2672a.html https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP2672AGD/document_id/9059/

Comment: Or google ... " 2 cell lithium-ion battery charger circuit "

Comment: Perhaps this, but read all, please. And  hx-2s needed https://www.ebay.com/itm/254258413047

Comment: Great @antonio51! I'm checking.

Comment: @antonio51, I have checked them, I can't wait for online delivery, and these modules are hard to find in my country. Is it ok to use the TP-5100 2s charger module instead of the LM-2596 step-down converter?

Comment: Seems to be ok. Note that your hx-12 should also be used ... Note also: Batteries in the "same" state before paralleling ! If you don't know, check "before", every voltage battery.

Comment: @antonio51 Thank you, I have made it : https://i.imgur.com/1TYQ9Jg.jpg , No overheat anymore!

Comment: For your information, https://robojax.com/learn/arduino/?vid=robojax_TP5100_charger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are short circuiting the buck module into the lithium battery which is dangerous. Mishandled batteries may become unstable and burst into fire and explode, so stop immediately what you are doint.

You have no lithium charger in the circuit.

What you think as a charger is not a charger but a battery management system and protection board, a BMS.

And a BMS is not a charger.

Comment: Thank you @justme!
Could you please look at this link: [amazon hx-2s](https://www.amazon.com/Anmbest-Charger-Protection-Lithium-Battery/dp/B07KSQY67X)
The image says the P- & P+ can be used for charging, What shall I do? Is there any component I use to charge batteries?

Comment: I have just researched the XL-4015, Is it ok if I connect the XL-4015 directly to the batteries? –

Comment: The Amazon link is correct, P- and P+ can be used for charging. With a lithium charger, obviously. XL-4015 is a buck converter chip, it is not a lithium charger chip. It is not OK to charge lithiums with anything else than a device intended to charge lithiums, safely.

Comment: Please check [Link](https://www.electroschematics.com/dc-module/), There is a LED to show the battery charge situation, Is it still improper to use it as a battery charger? So why do they design that module like this?

Comment: @masoudkhanlo These are SMPS DC-DC supplies, not really chargers for Li-ion batteries, although these have a current limit adjustable and because there **do not have**, at least, a **"voltage limit supervisor"** ...

Comment: Thank you @antonio51, I don't know What should I have done, Is there any resource that I can build a charging unit for my robot?

Comment: I think it might be safest to simply buy a charger instead of trying to build one.

Comment: @justme, I have to embed everything in a box. Is it possible to replace TP-5100 instead of LM-2596?